# Suggestions on using weekly at the beginning

Tags: sentence-construction

> Weekly, when we disbursed supplies to him, we would discuss that it would be a good idea for him to seek treatment for his condition.

This sentence sounds a little off. I am not sure if it would be appropriate to use in formal writing. I am wondering if weekly is used properly or if a different transition word can be used.  I want to know if I can start a sentence with "weekly" and if it reads well. It sounds a little awkward to me I guess. I also want to know if the commas are in the correct place.

Comment: Please tell us what you think is wrong in this sentence. Are you looking for an alternative word for something? Or do you want to know if the tenses used are correct? If their is missed punctuation that you wish to insert?? Please specify.

Comment: I think it’s perfect.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh i want to know if I can start a sentence with weekly and if it reads well. It sounds a little awkward to me I guess. I also want to know if the commas are in the correct place.

Comment: I think it would be more idiomatic to use "Every week" in this particular context.

Comment: Adverbs are often placed in initial position with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on context. If it has already been established that supplies were disbursed more often than weekly (such as daily), then the sentence is reasonable, as it establishes that his situation is being discussed each week.

If the supplies are only delivered once a week, I'd suggest that it would sound more natural to use something like, "During our weekly delivery of supplies ..."